GNS3 - Router doesn't forward DHCP Discover Messages
I wanted to post a picture of my network, but I don't have enough reputation, so I'm going to try to explain it without one:
I have a router R1 which is the DHCP Server for my Network, which is connected (Interface f0/0) to a switch (SW1) and (Interface f0/2) another router R2 (Interface f0/1) (which will be the DNS-Server). The Switch SW1 is connected to 3 hosts (H1-H3), H1 and H2 are in VLAN10 and H3 in VLAN20. The router R2 is also connected (Interface f0/2) to a switch SW2 which is also connected to 3 Hosts (H4-H6), H4-H5 is in VLAN30 and H6 in VLAN40.
I accomplished that R1 is giving Hosts 1-3 IP Addresses, but when I tried the same for Host 4-6 it didn't work. I tried to set up an IP Helper-Address for the VLAN30 and VLAN40 to forward the Discover Messages, but I didn't get it to work :(
Config for R1:
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 5
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
!
!
ip cef
no ip domain lookup
no ip dhcp use vrf connected
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.20.1
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.30.1
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.40.1
!
ip dhcp pool VLAN10
   network 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 192.168.10.1 
   dns-server 10.12.0.1 
!
ip dhcp pool VLAN20
   network 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 192.168.20.1 
   dns-server 10.12.0.1 
!
ip dhcp pool VLAN30
   network 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 192.168.30.1 
   dns-server 10.12.0.1 
!
ip dhcp pool VLAN40
   network 192.168.40.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 192.168.40.1 
   dns-server 10.12.0.1 
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no switchport
 ip address 10.13.0.1 255.255.255.252
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 no switchport
 ip address 10.12.0.1 255.255.255.252
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
!
interface Vlan10
 ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan20
 ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0
!
!
router ospf 1
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 10.12.0.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 10.13.0.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 10.31.0.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
!
no ip http server
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
!
no cdp log mismatch duplex
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end

Config for R2:
!

!
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R2
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 5
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
!
!
ip cef
ip domain name example.com
ip host R2 10.32.0.1
ip host R1 10.12.0.1
ip host R3 10.23.0.2
ip host R3.example.com 10.23.0.2
ip host R1.example.com 10.12.0.1
ip host R2.example.com 10.32.0.1
ip host google.com 8.8.8.8
ip name-server 10.12.0.2
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 no switchport
 ip address 10.23.0.1 255.255.255.252
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no switchport
 ip address 10.12.0.2 255.255.255.252
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
!
interface Vlan30
 ip address 192.168.30.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.12.0.1
!
!
router ospf 2
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 10.12.0.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 10.23.0.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 10.32.0.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
!
no ip http server
ip forward-protocol nd
!
ip dns server
!
!
no cdp log mismatch duplex
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end

I know VLAN40 doesn't have a Helper-Address yet, I just wanted to get it to work for VLAN30 first.

You need to create VLAN 30 before you can actually use it:
vlan 30
name VLAN30
end

You also need some access ports on that VLAN where the hosts are connected.

I already had the Access Ports, but you were right i needed to add the VLANs to the VLAN-Database of R2, thank you :)
